# Can I power an external stepper driver without motor connected?

Tags: stepper-driver, stepper

I have not used external stepper drivers yet, but I am using them in a new build.  I have an optional stepper driver that will be connected to a stepper motor for a rotary attachment.  Can I leave the stepper driver connected to the power supply, but disconnect the optional stepper motor when not in use?  Will powering the external stepper driver without a motor attached fry the driver?

Comment: Why not use a switch and sidestep the whole issue?

Comment: @Kilisi Mainly laziness.  I didn't think about the possiblity of it being an issue until I started hooking up the motors.  So I would have to take apart my electronics enclosure, drill another hole and add another switch.  I think at this point I will just unplug the power connector to that driver when I'm not using it.  I'm still curious if the external drivers can handle being powered without a motor connected.

Comment: I would think it's a risk not worth taking https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/345003/why-does-disconnecting-a-stepper-motor-while-powered-on-damage-the-driver

Comment: It won't hurt anything to power a stepper driver without a motor attached. They are just totems/hbridges that don't rely on load for stability or bias.